# Set OriginalValue property in VB6 classic ADO fabricated recordset

Tags: vb6, ado, recordset

In classic ADO in VB6, in a recordset that's come from an external source, say, `Set Rs = Conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM Table")`, each Field has an `OriginalValue` property, so that after an update to a record you can still see what the original value of each field was.

However, I'm working with a recordset built like so:

```
Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Rs.Fields.Append "Name", adVarChar, 100, adFldMayBeNull
Rs.Open
Rs.AddNew
Rs.Fields("Name").Value = "rudolph"
Rs.Update
```

But in this recordset, even if I change the value of a field, the OriginalValue property stays blank. Is there any way besides throwing the whole recordset to an XML stream, modifying the XML, and recreating the recordset to get OriginalValue to have the value I want?

I'm working with some previews of data changes where I have two recordsets, one representing the current values and one representing the original values. It's a pain, when needing to compare to see if something has changed, to have two objects instead of just one with two properties.

I know there is metadata inside a recordset about what its source table is, whether it's updatable, what the primary keys are, and what kind of properties the provider supports (such as `NextRecordset`), but some of them could be hard to access in a fabricated recordset such as I'm working with.

Also, could some locking setting such as `adLockBatchOptimistic` somehow be needed?

Comment: +1. Good question! BTW I think the official term is *disconnected* recordset.

Comment: @MarkJ: A disconnected recordset can also mean a recordset that was originally populated/updated by being connected to a data source but has since been disconnected by `Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing`. The term 'fabricated' is the one that appears in MSDN e.g. [The `Fields` Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676135(v=vs.85).aspx): "You can use the Append method to fabricate a Recordset programmatically without opening a connection to a data source." So a fabricated recordset is always disconnected but a disconnected recordset is not necessarily fabricated.

Comment: @onedaywhen I stand corrected :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line

```
rs.Update
```

with

```
rs.UpdateBatch
```

Comment: Wait, wait... I think I get it. `Update` (or an implicit Update such as `MoveNext`) just writes an edited single row to the in-memory recordset. `UpdateBatch` pushes all locally changed rows back to the original source (if there is one) and propagates the changes into the OriginalValue of the recordset. It's sort of weird this works because with a fabricated recordset there **is** no "original source."